# How do I make a php if/switch statement according to the PHP lang of the site?

Tags: php, if-statement, switch-statement

My site has a way of changing its language, and each time I change it I see something like this at the top of the source code:

```
<html dir="ltr" lang="en-US">
<html dir="ltr" lang="zh-TW">
```

I think using the URL may also work:

```
http://alexchen.info/en
http://alexchen.info/tw
```

or maybe this:

```
?lang=es
?lang=en
```

because this works too:

```
http://alexchen.info/?lang=es
http://alexchen.info/?lang=en
```

I would like to know what's the best way of using that to make a php if statement (or switch statement).
For instance:

```
if(lang=en) {
 // do this
}


if(lang=tw) {
 // do this
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have `?lang=en` you can simply get via the `$_GET` global variable. However, you should first encapsulate the logic within a function.

```
function getLang()
{
    return $_GET['lang'];
}

// ...

if (getLang() == 'en') {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: weird for some reason, doing `var_dump($_GET['lang']);`
 returns `NULL` where should I place that function?

Answer (score 1):

To write a switch (which could have easily been looked up in their [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php)):

```
switch($lang) {
    case 'en-US':
        // do this
        break;
    case 'zh-TW':
        // do this
        break;
}
```

Although this probably isn't the best approach to doing site translation. I haven't done much multi-language stuff myself, but I see a lot of frameworks wrap blocks of text in functions like

```
echo T("sample text");
```

And then the `T` function would replace that text with the translated text. That way you don't have you entire site littered with switch statements. The translations can be stored in a database. If there's a missing translation, that can be logged or inserted as a blank entry into your DB so that you know what you need to fill in/translate later without digging through your site trying to find all the places where text needs to be translated.

Comment: I do `_e('multilingual content')` for most of the site, but I have a text in a difficult function: `<?php next_post_link( '%link', 'Next Project ' . _x( '', 'next post link', 'twentyten' ) . '' ); ?>` and I can't figure out other way of doing it.

Comment: I don't understand the the difficulty here...do you want to translate "Next Project" or something?

Comment: Yes and it requires me to do something like this:     `<?php _e("<!--:en-->english text<!--:--><!--:de-->german text<!--:-->"); ?>` to translate things with a Wordpress plugin.